# Creating an ember.js table component with parameters

Tags: javascript, ember.js, html-table, components, ember-data

I'm trying to create a table component using ember.js. I need to pass, the table name, the columns header names and column names, and the table should be rendered accordingly. The number of columns vary per table.

But my code is not working with parameters passed as a list. Here's the part of the code:

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
     <h1> Testing Table 1</h1>
     {{table-ember tableName="Table 1" noOfColumns="3" columnHeaders="['LineID', 'Placement Name', 'Pricing Type']"  columnNames="['lineId', 'name', 'pricingType']"}}

     <h1>Testing Table 2</h1>
     {{table-ember tableName="Table 2" noOfColumns="2" columnHeaders="['LineID', 'Placement Name']"  columnNames="['lineId', 'name']"}}
 </script>

 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/table-ember">
    <p>{{tableName}}</p>
      {{#if columnHeaders}}     
        <table>
         <thead>
          {{#each columnHeaders}}
             <tr>
               <th>{{columnHeaders}}</th>
            </tr>
          {{/each}}
        </thead>

         {{#each}}
         <tr>
           <td>{{#link-to 'columnName' this}}{{columnNames}}{{/link-to}}</td>
         </tr>
         {{/each}}
      </table>
     {{/if}}
 </script>
```

Comment: Mind putting that in a jsbin?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/tayegori/7/edit?html,js,output